# User authentication in LDAP java

Tags: java, ldap, jndi, openldap

i am new to the **LDAP** concept and i am able to connect to the LDAP server successfully. And also able to insert and delete records to/from LDAP database. Next thing i need to do is authenticate the user based on LDAP database records..
Help me out please.
I will share the source code if needed.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have [several samples](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/JNDI%20Examples) which can help you if you need to use JNDI and LDAP.

We prefer to use a real LDAP SDK like the ones shown at https://www.ldap.com/developing-clients-apps (We use and reccomend UnboundID LDAP SDK for Java)

You should probably also consider using [OpenID Connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openid-connect) as you can then abstract the Authentication to become agnostic to how authentication takes place.

Answer (score 0):

I also used LDAP for auth. I recommand the **token based auth**. If you can obtain the `JWT` token by request. This repo [java-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt) will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind to use Spring Security, check out [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ldap.html) article. It will ease the implementation and configuration. Here is and example of LDAP configuration:

```
auth.authenticationProvider(ldapAuthenticationProvider)
    .ldapAuthentication()
    .ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(ldapAuthoritiesPopulator)
    .userSearchBase("ou=users")
    .userSearchFilter("(uid={0})")
    .groupSearchBase("ou=roles")
    .groupSearchFilter("(member={0})")
    .groupRoleAttribute("cn")
    .contextSource(contextSource);
```

Comment: Hello @Serghey.. Is there any way to use this in core java?

Comment: I'm not sure if Spring Security works well with core java, have never tried it. It this case you rather need Spring Ldap. Check [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/reference/#basic-authentication) example of Ldap basic authentication with Spring Ldap.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create an Object of InitialDirContext with security_principal(user dn) and security_credentials(password) of the user you want to authenticate. If you are able to create the object the user is authenticated else catch the exception and throw it.